# Show image based on user Id

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress page and I'm trying to include a HTML block to show the image that has the same name of the user id.

Flow:

1. The user (e.g. User_id=2) can upload a photo through a form.
2. I store the photo in the uploads folder and name it with the user_id.
3. The user logs into the personal area and has access to a page where I show that photo.

If I add this code in an HTML block, it does show the right photo, but it's of course not dynamically changing for each user.
`<img src=/wp-content/uploads/2.jpeg alt=2.jpeg/>`

I've tried to substitute `2` with `get_current_user_id()` but it doesn't load any image. 
I've also tried to assign the value returned by get_current_user_id() to a variable and then call that variable in the image path but this also returns no image.

`<?html var userid=get_current_user_id() img src=/wp-content/uploads/userid.jpeg alt=userid.jpeg/>`

I'm new to html, but I imagine this should be something relatively simple to do? Can someone help point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
I'm now using this PHP function to get the user ID through a shortcode:

```
function custom_shortcode_func_id() {
        ob_start();
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo $current_user->ID . '<br />';
        $output = ob_get_clean();
        return $output;
        }
        add_shortcode('current_user_ID', 'custom_shortcode_func_id');
```

but still unsure on how to integrate this ID in the image path. Does that have to happen on PHP side as well? 
Is the ideal solution I should be working towards something like (A) a shortcode that shows the image directly from PHP? or is it more of (B) a shortcode that prints an html code (like the one above, but each time with the right ID) and then the html shows the image?

I have tried multiple variations of substituting something like this code below to the previous echo statement. But it always breaks the website.

```
$photobyID= "/wp-content/uploads/".$current_user->ID."jpeg";
echo ‘<img src=“’.$photobyID.‘”>’;
```

I also tried to move the echo statement above on the html side like this:

`<img src="<?php echo $photobyID; ?>" alt=2.jpeg/>`

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference between static HTML and server-side-generated ("dynamic") HTML and the templating system of WordPress?

Comment: HTML is not dynamic. You need to use a server side language (PHP in your case as you are using Wordpress) that will generate the HTML on the front end. If you are not familiar with programming basics, then you will need to learn how to program to understand how to make changes to Wordpress themes, or get some one else to do this for you.

Comment: Thank you @flomei, I wasn't familiar with it but I'm studying and starting to understand more. I edited the question above after your tip. Is solution B what I should be working towards?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks for the advice. I have worked on the PHP side as you recommended. Got one step closer I think. any tips on next steps? kind of lost on integrating the html above in the php function... I keep on breaking the website with fatal errors

Comment: When you say it "breaks the site", what exactly do you mean? e.g. are you getting an error message, is there anything in the console, do you get a blank screen etc. Also, what happens when you used `<img src="<?php echo $photobyID; ?>" alt=2.jpeg/>`, Just knowing it broke the site doesn't give us anything to go on, so describing exactly what that means gives us more information that could help us work out *why* it broke, especially if there is an error message that can give us more information :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten it was giving a generic "fatal error" with no details and locking me out of the site. Until I'd go back and remove the piece of code from the function.php file of the theme. I think it was due to the use of single quotes vs double quotes, because it eventually worked with the code below :)

Answer (score 0):

This code shows the photo that is named the same as the user id.

```
function custom_shortcode_func_id_pic() {
        ob_start();
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $current_user_id=$current_user->ID ;
            echo '<img src=/wp-content/uploads'.$current_user_id.'.png >';
        $output = ob_get_clean();
        return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode('current_user_picture', 'custom_shortcode_func_id_pic');
```